# Getting the array index key to variable - 2D PHP array

Tags: php, json

I have searched for many places for an answer I couldn't find one, so please help me sort out this. - Thanks in advance

I have an Json String

```
{"first":{"val":100},"second":{"val":200},"third":{"val":300}}
```

which has been decoded and that has been saved in an php array

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

Now I tried to obtain those first, second, etc... values to concatenate with an sql query, but I couldn't get this sorted, so far I have tried like below,

```
foreach ($arr as $assoc) {
    foreach ($assoc as $value) {

        $val=$value+0;

        $sqlI = "UPDATE tblName SET fieldName = ".$val." WHERE fieldName1=".$assoc;
        $conn->query($sqlI);
    }
}
```

*Note: the fieldName1 will have unique values..

I am getting **Notice: Array to string conversion** error I understand this due to $assoc is an array type but how to get the key from this array?

Comment: `tblField=.$assoc`... what else do you expect? `$assoc` is the array you're looping on in the inner `foreach()`... maybe you meant `$value`? if you want the key from foreach, then use the `foreach($array as $key => $value)` syntax

Comment: or maybe you intend to update

Comment: Marc B, thank you for your respond: inner loop is for handle the 2D array I tried the way you mentioned above, I think this is helpful for if I want the value, but i want the array index, eg: $arr['first']['val']=100..... then I need the first in the sql command?? @@ :(

Comment: You caught me there DONT PANIC, and yes it supposed to be Update GHOST! but still same question remains???

Comment: Modified with the update, still probs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array would look like this:

```
$arr = Array(
   'first' => array(
       'val' => 100
   ),
   'second' => array(
       'val' => 200
   ),
   'thirth' => array(
       'val' => 300
   ),
);
```

You can access them like so:

```
echo $arr['first']['val']; // 100
```

Loop trough them like so:

```
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val['val']; // 100, 200, 300.
}
```

Or with key:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    echo "current key: '$key' with val '". $val['val'] ."'";
}
```

Comment: Awesome Xorifelse.. just done it! Thank you very much to point out that $val['val'] part! :)